# How to add a fallback when :b buffer change fails

Tags: buffers, the-silver-searcher, plugin-fzf

I have 2 ways to open a file for editing:

1. `:b <filename>` to switch to an opened buffer -- imagine that I have a lot of folders containing `index.html` so by using `:b` I know I am working on the one that I should be working on.
2. Fuzzy File Search (`:FZF`) just in case I haven't opened the file or I have killed the buffer with `:bd`.

**My question:** Is there a way to automate, such that if `:b <filename>` fails (E94: No matching buffer), nvim will call `:FZF` and use `<filename>` to search?

P.S. It'd be best if I used `:b107` and I mistyped the number, `FZF` will not be triggered. (distinguishing cases whether I use `:b` with string or number)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't change the way the `:b` command works, but you can create an alternative `:B` command, and then create an abbreviation to always use the `:B` command when you type `:b`.

The below works by first trying using the `:b` command, and if the E94 error is thrown, doing a `:FZF` instead:

```
function! BWithFallback(buffer_name) abort
  " Check if the input is a number or a string
  if a:buffer_name =~# '^\d\+$'
    execute 'b' a:buffer_name
  else
    try
      " Try opening the buffer
      execute 'b' a:buffer_name
    catch /E94/
      " If the buffer didn't exist, try doing a fuzzy file search
      " using the command provided by the OP.
      execute 'FZF -q' a:buffer_name
    endtry
  endif
endfunction

" Create new :B command. You could also use -complete=file if you prefer
command! -nargs=1 -complete=buffer B call BWithFallback('<args>')

" When you type :b, replace it with :B
cnoreabbrev <expr> b (getcmdtype() == ':' && getcmdline() ==# 'b') ? 'B' : b
```

Comment: Maybe a nice addition would be to use `-complete=buffer` and/or `-complete=file` to the `command!` command to allow some autocompletion like the original `:b` does.

Comment: @statox Great point!

Comment: Thank you! One more question: (Verified with vim, strange) If I have opened a file named `index.php`, even after I `:bd` and `:ls` to verify that the buffer is deleted, `:B index` will not go to the else case.. while `:b index` returns E94.
By the way, for `fzf` it is `execute 'FZF -q '.a:buffer_name`.  Spent time finding ways to type in Terminal Emulator and in vain..

Comment: @SunnyPun I thought you requested that it doesn't ever call FZF if you pass in a number. If I've misunderstood you, you can just remove the if `block` and keep only the contents of the else `block`. Thanks for confirming the `fzf` command. I'll add that into the answer.

Comment: @Rich Nope you didn’t misunderstand me. My aforementioned problem is, I typed a non-numeric partial file name (index.php), instead of calling FZF, it reopened a buffer that I deleted with `:bd`. However if I used `:b index.php` it won’t open the deleted buffer. And I want `:B` to resort to FZF when there is no opened buffer corresponding to the partial name.

Comment: @SunnyPun When you use `:bd`, it closes the buffer, but doesn't remove all knowledge of it. The command `:ls!` will show *all* buffers, even deleted ones. Thus, `:b partialname` still opens the buffer. (However, `:b fullname` will *also* still open it: I don't know why Vim doesn't exhibit that behaviour for you.) This is Vim's default behaviour. If you don't want this to occur, you'll need to use `:bwipeout` to remove the buffer *completely*, but [be aware of what this actually does](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/2212/what-bad-things-can-happen-if-i-use-bwipeout) before doing so.